# Toast.makeText not showing (not .show)

Tags: android, kotlin

As the title states, I am trying to get my Toast.makeText to show a message, but it isn't showing. I'm not sure if it is my xml file or something. Below is the code in kotlin.

```
LockButton.setOnClickListener {
             if (i == 1) {
                 Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Unlocked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                 GlobalScope.launch {
                     val url = URL(ipcomm2)
                     val con: HttpURLConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
                        try {
                          val `in`: InputStream = BufferedInputStream(con.inputStream)
                          `in`.read()
                        } finally {
                          con.disconnect()
                        }
                 }
                     i = 0
             }
                 else if (i == 0) {
                     Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Locked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                     GlobalScope.launch {
                         val url2 = URL(ipcomm2)
                         val con2: HttpURLConnection = url2.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
                             try {
                                 val inp: InputStream = BufferedInputStream(con2.inputStream)
                                 inp.read()
                             } finally {
                                 con2.disconnect()
                             }

                     }
                     i = 1
                 }
             }
```

Comment: What is `i` initialised to?

Comment: Use debugger breakpoints to see why these code blocks aren't being reached. Probably `i` is not the value you're expecting.

Comment: Adding to @Tenfour04,  You can put one toast also before if condition to check if it is toast issue or condition issue like Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Test!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

Comment: I've tested that the code runs even though the toast doesn't show, and when I test it outside the code block it still doesn't show

Answer (score 0):

I think i value is not 0,1. I recommended to you use a boolean variable instead of int and use the (else) part instead of (else if).